# many-to-many-to-many accessor using DBIx::Class

Tags: perl, many-to-many, catalyst, dbix-class

Using DBIx::Class, I am trying to create a many-to-many accessor (or even just a has-many relationship) that spans two link tables.

The three data tables in question are **Users**, **Roles** and **Pages**, with the two link tables **UserRoles** and **RolePages**.  These tables are related thus:

- a **User** has many **UserRoles**
- a **Role** has many **UserRoles**
- a **Role** has many **RolePages**
- a **Page** has many **RolePages**

The Catalyst helper script created these relationships and accessors for me:

```
package MyApp::Schema::Result::User;

__PACKAGE__->has_many(
  "user_roles",
  "MyApp::Schema::Result::UserRole",
  { "foreign.username" => "self.username" },
  { cascade_copy => 0, cascade_delete => 0 },
);

__PACKAGE__->many_to_many("roles", "user_roles", "role");


package MyApp::Schema::Result::Role;

__PACKAGE__->has_many(
  "role_pages",
  "MyApp::Schema::Result::RolePage",
  { "foreign.role" => "self.role" },
  { cascade_copy => 0, cascade_delete => 0 },
);

__PACKAGE__->has_many(
  "user_roles",
  "MyApp::Schema::Result::UserRole",
  { "foreign.role" => "self.role" },
  { cascade_copy => 0, cascade_delete => 0 },
);

__PACKAGE__->many_to_many("page_names", "role_pages", "page_name")

__PACKAGE__->many_to_many("usernames", "user_roles", "username");


package MyApp::Schema::Result::Page;

__PACKAGE__->has_many(
  "role_pages",
  "MyApp::Schema::Result::RolePage",
  { "foreign.page_name" => "self.page_name" },
  { cascade_copy => 0, cascade_delete => 0 },
);

__PACKAGE__->many_to_many("roles", "role_pages", "role");


package MyApp::Schema::Result::UserRole;

__PACKAGE__->belongs_to(
  "role",
  "MyApp::Schema::Result::Role",
  { role => "role" },
  { is_deferrable => 1, on_delete => "CASCADE", on_update => "CASCADE" },
);

__PACKAGE__->belongs_to(
  "username",
  "MyApp::Schema::Result::User",
  { username => "username" },
  { is_deferrable => 1, on_delete => "CASCADE", on_update => "CASCADE" },
);


package MyApp::Schema::Result::RolePage;

__PACKAGE__->belongs_to(
  "page_name",
  "MyApp::Schema::Result::Page",
  { page_name => "page_name" },
  { is_deferrable => 1, on_delete => "CASCADE", on_update => "CASCADE" },
);

__PACKAGE__->belongs_to(
  "role",
  "MyApp::Schema::Result::Role",
  { role => "role" },
  { is_deferrable => 1, on_delete => "CASCADE", on_update => "CASCADE" },
);
```

My end goal is to have a clean way to get a list of the pages that should be displayed for the current user.  I.e.:

```
foreach my $page ($c->user->pages) {
    # do something with $page
}
```

I did have this method in the MyApp::Schema::Result::User class:

```
sub pages {
    my ($self) = @_;

    return $self->result_source->schema->resultset('RolePage')->search(
        {
            'username.username' => $self->username,
        },
        {
            join => [
                {
                    role => {user_roles => 'username'},
                },
                'page_name',
            ],
        }
    );
}
```

which worked until I added a class to extend MyApp::Schema::Result::RolePage.  That class starts off like this:

```
package MyApp::Schema::ResultSet::RolePage;

use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;
extends qw/MyApp::Schema::ResultSetX::DisplayTable/;

has '+name' => ( default => 'RolePage' );
```

I've used this technique throughout my app, to create various result sets, and have only run into trouble with it now.  I get this error:

> Caught exception in Lifeway::Controller::Root->auto "Single parameters to new() must be a HASH ref

which is caused by my `MyApp::Schema::Result::User->pages()` method. So, to avoid this error, I thought I'd try to create a many-to-many accessor (or even just a has-many relationship) from **Users** to **Pages**.

Is it possible to create such an accessor/relationship that spans two link tables?  If so, how?  I can't find an example in the docs, and have run out of ideas myself.  Failing that, any ideas on why I'm getting that error with my pages() method?

Comment: The search method will return a single object rather than a ResultSet when there is only one item in the RS (or undef if no match is found) - does the problem go away if you change it to ->search_rs(...), forcing it to always return a ResultSet?

Comment: No, unfortunately I still get the `Single parameters to new() must be a HASH ref` error.  It's probably better to keep it as `search_rs`, though, to ensure it returns a predictable data type.  Thanks.

Comment: That error looks like a Moose error, not a DBIx error.  Somewhere you are calling new() with a single non-hashref argument - are you sure the problem is in DBIx?  Can you create a $user instance and call $user->pages() directly to see if it is returning what you think it is?

Comment: You're right.  The exception is raised in `/opt/ActivePerl-5.14/site/lib/Moose/Object.pm`.

Comment: I put `die Dumper $c->user->pages;` at the start of my root controller.  It seemed to return something sensible for both your new `pages()` method (as mentioned below) and my old one.  However, my old method causes the error when used in this statement: `$c->user->pages->search(undef, {columns => ['page_name'], distinct => 1, order_by => 'sort_order'})->get_column('page_name')->all`

Comment: I'm not sure if you can pass undef as the first argument to search - it might need to be an empty hashref instead.

Comment: `->pages->search(undef,...)` seems to work ok, once I have a good `pages()` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no built-in support for many-to-many-to-many relationships, but it's not too hard to roll your own.

In Schema::Result::User.pm

```
sub pages {
  my $self = shift;
  return $self->search_related('user_roles')
    ->search_related('role')
    ->search_related('role_pages')
    ->search_related('page_name');
    # Alternatively, if you need to eliminate duplicates:
    # ->search_related('page_name', {}, {distinct => 1});
}
```

This is pretty close to a functional equivalent to a standard DBIx many-to-many relationship bridge, I think.